# How can i add a javascript pattern matching like "aaaa" and "aaa aaa" both

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a pattern that can take both string with space and without space in same text box. how to do this?

Comment: So what is the pattern that works without the space, what are the rules? What did you try?

Comment: Add examples of strings that should 'match' and some that should not 'match' your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
var patron = /^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/;
```

try it.

Comment: It is far more helpful if you explain _why_ you think your answer is correct instead of just saying "try it".  Maybe show your example inputs and the resulting output.